# How to put labels over geom_bar in R with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to have some labels stacked on top of a `geom_bar` graph. Here's an example:

```
df <- data.frame(x=factor(c(TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE)))
ggplot(df) + geom_bar(aes(x,fill=x)) + opts(axis.text.x=theme_blank(),axis.ticks=theme_blank(),axis.title.x=theme_blank(),legend.title=theme_blank(),axis.title.y=theme_blank())
```

[image]

Now

> table(df$x)

```
FALSE  TRUE 
    3     5
```

I'd like to have the 3 and 5 on top of the two bars. Even better if I could have the percent values as well. E.g. `3 (37.5%)` and `5 (62.5%)`. Like so:
[image]
<sub>(source: [skitch.com](https://img.skitch.com/20110623-xhbdwqj9bicqsf8nurg9dkuqsi.png))</sub>

Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: Adding numbers or text at the tops of bars distorts how the eye sees the comparison in heights. See [this discusssion](http://tolstoy.newcastle.edu.au/R/e2/help/07/08/22858.html) on R-help.

Comment: Thanks for adding this in Greg. I'd only suggest saying "Adding numbers or text...may distort how the eye...". I think the context for every chart is different and I have seen very rare cases where you can make generalizations about design.

Comment: The argument `vjust` inside `geom_text` is the key for your answer!

Answer (score 42, accepted):

As with many tasks in ggplot, the general strategy is to put what you'd like to add to the plot into a data frame in a way such that the variables match up with the variables and aesthetics in your plot. So for example, you'd create a new data frame like this:

```
dfTab <- as.data.frame(table(df))
colnames(dfTab)[1] <- "x"
dfTab$lab <- as.character(100 * dfTab$Freq / sum(dfTab$Freq))
```

So that the `x` variable matches the corresponding variable in `df`, and so on. Then you simply include it using `geom_text`:

```
ggplot(df) + geom_bar(aes(x,fill=x)) + 
    geom_text(data=dfTab,aes(x=x,y=Freq,label=lab),vjust=0) +
    opts(axis.text.x=theme_blank(),axis.ticks=theme_blank(),
        axis.title.x=theme_blank(),legend.title=theme_blank(),
        axis.title.y=theme_blank())
```

This example will plot just the percentages, but you can `paste` together the counts as well via something like this:

```
dfTab$lab <- paste(dfTab$Freq,paste("(",dfTab$lab,"%)",sep=""),sep=" ")
```

Note that in the current version of ggplot2, `opts` is deprecated, so we would use `theme` and `element_blank` now.

Answer (score 73):

To plot text on a `ggplot` you use the `geom_text`.  But I find it helpful to summarise the data first using `ddply`

```
dfl <- ddply(df, .(x), summarize, y=length(x))
str(dfl)
```

Since the data is pre-summarized, you need to remember to change add the `stat="identity"` parameter to `geom_bar`:

```
ggplot(dfl, aes(x, y=y, fill=x)) + geom_bar(stat="identity") +
    geom_text(aes(label=y), vjust=0) +
    opts(axis.text.x=theme_blank(),
        axis.ticks=theme_blank(),
        axis.title.x=theme_blank(),
        legend.title=theme_blank(),
        axis.title.y=theme_blank()
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 20):

Another solution is to use `stat_count()` when dealing with discrete variables (and `stat_bin()` with continuous ones).

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x)) +
geom_bar(stat = "count") + 
stat_count(geom = "text", colour = "white", size = 3.5,
aes(label = ..count..),position=position_stack(vjust=0.5))
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

So, this is our initial plot↓

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(x=factor(c(TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE)))

p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = x, fill = x)) +
  geom_bar()
p
```

[image: initial barplot without labels]

As suggested by [yuan-ning](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62975905/3443500), we can use `stat_count()`.

`geom_bar()` uses `stat_count()` by default. As mentioned in the ggplot2 [reference](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_bar.html#computed-variables), `stat_count()` returns two values: `count` for number of points in bin and `prop` for groupwise proportion. Since our groups match the x values, both `prop`s are 1 and aren’t useful. But we can use `count` (referred to as “..count..”) that actually denotes bar heights, in our `geom_text()`. Note that we must include “stat = 'count'” into our `geom_text()` call as well.

Since we want both counts and percentages in our labels, we’ll need some calculations and string pasting in our “label” aesthetic instead of just “..count..”. I prefer to add a line of code to create a wrapper percent formatting function from the “scales” package (ships along with “ggplot2”).

```
pct_format = scales::percent_format(accuracy = .1)

p <- p + geom_text(
    aes(
      label = sprintf(
        '%d (%s)',
        ..count..,
        pct_format(..count.. / sum(..count..))
      )
    ),
    stat = 'count',
    nudge_y = .2,
    colour = 'royalblue',
    size = 5
  )
p
```

[image: barplot with labels]

Of course, you can further edit the labels with `colour`, `size`, nudges, adjustments etc. or use `glue::glue()` instead of `sprintf()` if you want.

**UPD:** The ggplot2 authors now [insist](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/aes_eval.html) on using `after_stat(something)` instead of the usual `..something..` notation. Therefore, the up-to-date version of the second part (adding labels) is now a bit more bulky, but produces the exact same result:

```
pct_format = scales::percent_format(accuracy = .1)

p <- p + geom_text(
  aes(
    label = sprintf(
      '%d (%s)',
      after_stat(count),
      pct_format(after_stat(count) / sum(after_stat(count)))
    )
  ),
  stat = 'count',
  nudge_y = .2,
  colour = 'royalblue',
  size = 5
)
```