# How to put labels over geom_bar for each bar in R with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I've found this, [How to put labels over geom_bar in R with ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6455088/how-to-put-labels-over-geom-bar-in-r-with-ggplot2), but it just put labels(numbers) over only one bar.

Here is, let's say, two bars for each x-axis, how to do the same thing?

My data and code look like this:

```
dat <- read.table(text = "sample Types Number
sample1 A   3641
sample2 A   3119
sample1 B   15815
sample2 B   12334
sample1 C   2706
sample2 C   3147", header=TRUE)

library(ggplot2)
bar <- ggplot(data=dat, aes(x=Types, y=Number, fill=sample)) + 
  geom_bar(position = 'dodge') + geom_text(aes(label=Number))
```

Then, we'll get:
[image]

It seems that the number texts are also positioned in the "dodge" pattern.
I've searched [geom_text manual](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_text.html) to find some information, but cannot make it work.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 185, accepted):

Try this:

```
ggplot(data=dat, aes(x=Types, y=Number, fill=sample)) + 
     geom_bar(position = 'dodge', stat='identity') +
     geom_text(aes(label=Number), position=position_dodge(width=0.9), vjust=-0.25)
```

[image: ggplot output]

Comment: (+1) You could also add `vjust = -0.5` after the `position()` statement so that the values are placed just above the bars.

Comment: Great thanks, by the way, the code suggests  setting `ymax`, so  `aes(x=Types, y=Number, fill=sample, ymax = 16000)`, will produce wider upper area for y-axis, so that 15815 will get better shown.

Comment: I get this error: Error: stat_count() must not be used with a y aesthetic.

Comment: this answer has newer  syntax http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33079500/geom-text-with-dodged-barplot?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: How can I change the orientation of the label in the case the histogram was rotated horizontally?

Comment: @Seymour `geom_text(..., angle=-90)`

Comment: This works also with `geom_label`: `geom_label(position=position_dodge(width=0.9))`. But why the 0.9?

Answer (score 5):

To add to rcs' answer, if you want to use position_dodge() with geom_bar() when x is a POSIX.ct date, you must multiply the width by 86400, e.g.,

```
ggplot(data=dat, aes(x=Types, y=Number, fill=sample)) + 
 geom_bar(position = "dodge", stat = 'identity') +
 geom_text(aes(label=Number), position=position_dodge(width=0.9*86400), vjust=-0.25)
```