# Negative Labels hidden by bar in ggplot: geom_bar

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is an extension question to: [How to put labels over geom_bar for each bar in R with ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12018499/how-to-put-labels-over-geom-bar-for-each-bar-in-r-with-ggplot2)

My data has some negatives and so the labels intrude into the bar. How can I adjust this? I need the label placements to be read dynamically.

Thanks!

```
growth<-data.frame(ElapsedTimeMonths=c(3,6,12,24),MedianGrowth=c(-0.011,-0.002,0.014,0.052))
g<-ggplot(growth, aes(x=factor(ElapsedTimeMonths),y=MedianGrowth))
g<-g+geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity")
g<-g+scale_y_continuous(labels = percent)
g<-g+geom_text(aes(label=as.character(100*MedianGrowth)), position=position_dodge(width=0.9), vjust=-0.25)
g
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Graphical parameter settings can be vectors so that different
shapes (geom text here)can have different appearances.

You need to give **vjust** as a vector, with **opposite sign** of MedianGrowth

Your data

```
growth <- data.frame(ElapsedTimeMonths=c(3,6,12,24),
                   MedianGrowth=c(-0.011,-0.002,0.014,0.052),
                  )
```

I create the vjust vector

```
 vvjust <- rep(1, length(growth$MedianGrowth))
 vvjust[growth$MedianGrowth > 0 ] <- -0.25
 [1]  1.00  1.00 -0.25 -0.25
```

Then I plot

```
g<- ggplot(growth, aes(x=factor(ElapsedTimeMonths),y=MedianGrowth))
g<- g+ geom_bar(stat='identity',position='dodge')
g<- g+ scale_y_continuous(labels = percent)
g<- g+ geom_text(aes(label=as.character(100*MedianGrowth)), 
                 position=position_dodge(width=0.9), vjust=vvjust)
```

[image]