# Showing counts in bar plot - factor

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I have this graphic in ggplot2 and I would like to add in graph counts in each segment or percentage maybe. Counts are in table here

`kod` is factor of 5 groups
`stamg` is factor 0/1

```
ggplot(databak, aes(factor(kod), fill = factor(stamg))) +
  geom_bar(position = "fill")
```

[image: that is my geom bar plot without counts]

[image: this is a table of counts]

Comment: Use `geom_text()` as explained in this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12018499/how-to-put-labels-over-geom-bar-for-each-bar-in-r-with-ggplot2)

Comment: I am sorry, but I don´t get it. How can I create y variable of counts? Please, write me the code geom_text, thank you!

Comment: Your question could use some editing...
you are using databak (a data frame I presume) to generate your plot (right?) but then you provide another dataframe (doesn't look like its databak).
Is that last dataframe extra information which you want to use in the plot?