# Dodging labels in ggpubr

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

I'm trying to create an interaction barplot with mean separation letters placed above each bar. I cannot figure out how to position labels so that they are dodged. Any help would be appreciated.

Here I'm using data based off the toothgrowth dataset:

```
df2 <- data.frame(supp=rep(c("VC", "OJ"), each=3),
              dose=rep(c("D0.5", "D1", "D2"),2),
              len=c(6.8, 15, 33, 4.2, 10, 29.5))
ggbarplot(df2, "dose", "len",color="supp",fill="supp", 
       label = c("bc","c","a","a","ab","bc"), position = position_dodge(.8))
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide some data so we can try to resolve the issue. A popular approach is reproducing the problem with built in data like `diamonds`, `mtcars` etc.

Comment: Sorry about that - small data set added.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12018499/how-to-put-labels-over-geom-bar-for-each-bar-in-r-with-ggplot2

Comment: Why not use bare *ggplot* instead of wrap up package *ggpubr*, especially when the plot is a simple barplot? See above link if it is works, then we can close this post.

Comment: One of the aspects I like about ggpubr, which is not shown in the code above, is the ease in which I can place standard error bars. I know this can be done with ggplot, but I prefer ggpubr for its ease.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this acceptable?

```
df2 <- data.frame(supp=rep(c("VC", "OJ"), each=3),
                  dose=rep(c("D0.5", "D1", "D2"),2),
                  len=c(6.8, 15, 33, 4.2, 10, 29.5),
                  label = c("bc","c","a","a","ab","bc"))

 ggbarplot(df2, "dose", "len",color="supp",fill="supp", label = "label",
               position = position_dodge(0.8), lab.col = "supp")
```

[image]