# Adding data labels above geom_col() chart with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have tried to add data labels that show the sum of y values for a given x category.  Here is the code I used:

```
library(ggplot2)
gg <- ggplot(vgsales, aes(x = Genre, y = Global_Sales, fill = Genre)) + 
geom_col() + 
geom_text(aes(x = Genre, y = Global_Sales, label = Global_Sales), stat = "sum")
print(gg)
```

This is the result I get: [image]

I would like to position the labels above each bar and show only the sum of all y values for a given x.  How do I accomplish this?

Edit: I've attempted to use some of the guides mentioned and the result is this:

[image]

So the labels appear to be overlapping each other and reporting individual Global_Sales sums.  Is there a way just to report the total Global_Sales by genre as a label?

Comment: Have you looked around for similar problems on SO? For example, you problem looks very similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12018499/how-to-put-labels-over-geom-bar-for-each-bar-in-r-with-ggplot2?rq=1).

Comment: If I use your code on some simulated data, the labels are right at the top of each bar. Maybe update your packages.

Comment: @Imo I did, and unfortunately when I try to replicate from those instructions I am unsuccessful.  The link you supplied talks about putting a data label above a bar chart for a singular value.  However, I'm trying to create a data label for a sum of values.

Comment: @MartinSchmelzer I downloaded ggplot2 this morning to my home PC in r studio, and no packages require updating.  Would you mind sharing with me what you did?

Comment: Just generated a data.frame with `Genre = LETTERS[1:10]` and `Global_Sales = round(runif(10,100,500))` and then used your code.

Answer (score 24):

I was able to find a solution by creating another data frame from my existing data frame using the `aggregate` function.  This was the result:

```
library(ggplot2)
m3 <- aggregate(vgsales$Global_Sales, by=list(Genre=vgsales$Genre), FUN = sum)
m3 <- as.data.frame(m3)
names(m3) <- c("Genre", "Global_Sales")
gg <- ggplot(m3, aes(x = Genre, y = Global_Sales, fill = Genre)) + 
geom_col() +
geom_text(aes(label = Global_Sales), vjust = -0.5)
print(gg)
```

[image]

Edit: Data can be found here: [Video Game Sales (via Kaggle)](https://www.kaggle.com/gregorut/videogamesales)

Comment: It would be better to share the `data` which has been used to create this graph. It will be helpful to future.

Comment: @MKR Done.  The data is from Kaggle's website.

Comment: Good answer. No other example had answer to this. You might now know the reason why your earlier solution was not working. `geom_text` expects only 1 value per bar(in case of multiple value it was printing all). Another way to write your solution could as `df %>% group_by(Genre) %>%
  summarise(Global_Sales = sum(Global_Sales)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Genre, y=Global_Sales, fill=Genre)) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_text(aes(label = Global_Sales), position = position_dodge(width = 0.9), vjust = -0.25)`.

Comment: Thank you @MKR for the additional solution.  I am just learning R and one of the things I keep seeing is the `%>%` feature, which is something that is new to me.  I will research this and start practicing with it.

Comment: for anyone looking to replicate the number above the column, the relevant line is `geom_text(aes(label = global sales), vjust = -0.5)`

Comment: For anyone here for plotnine, use `nudge_y` [doc](https://plotnine.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generated/plotnine.geoms.geom_text.html)

Answer (score 6):

Modifying an example from [this](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_text.html) website, I think you should be able to do something along the lines of:

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame( x = factor(c(1, 1, 2, 2)), y = c(1, 3, 2, 1), grp = c("a", "b", "a", "b"))

ggplot(data = df, aes(x, y, group = grp)) +
geom_col(aes(fill = grp), position = "dodge") + 
geom_text(aes(label = mean(y), y = y + 0.05), position = position_dodge(0.9), vjust = 0)
```

So, basically, just make the label=mean(Global_Sales). The positioning of y as Global_Sales+0.05 will let it rise just slightly over the bar so it's legible. 
[This is the plot I made. Hopefully the link works.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQ2ZX.png)

Comment: Using your code, [this is what I get](https://imgur.com/a/GfByN).  Any way to not have the data labels repeat themselves?  Also the values do not appear to be correct.

Comment: Hmm. I also see that I answered for mean...may I ask what 'n' is? I'm not sure where that legend is coming from, given the code you're showing. Especially as your code looks like it should give the right result.

Comment: n should not exist.  What I'm trying to do is take the total Global Sales for each genre and add it as a label above each bar.  For whatever reason I cannot seem to do this with my code.

Answer (score 6):

The very quick answer is

```
+ geom_text(aes(label = Global_Sales), vjust = -0.5)
```