# How can I add labels to bar chart with ggplot2 if using a melted data.table?

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, bar-chart, melt

I am using a melted data.table:

```
cat <- melt(as.data.table(insti), id.vars=c(1:3,11), measure.vars=4:10)
```

which I used to create a plot:

```
  ggplot(cat,
         aes(x=reorder(Llengua, -Publicacions),
             y=Publicacions, fill=Xarxa))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity")+#nº de publicacions
  theme_classic()+
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90, hjust=0.8, vjust=0.5), legend.position="top")+
  labs(x="Llengua")+
  ggtitle("Catalunya")+
  geom_text(aes(label =Percentatge), vjust = 0.5)+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5))+
  scale_fill_manual(values=col.Xarxa)+
  geom_hline(yintercept=0.333*sum(cat$Publicacions),
             linetype="dashed", color = "dark grey")
```

which looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tEUoF.png)

my question is: how can I add percentage or absolute values labels for every single column (don't take in consideration the color divisions) if every column comes from the total sum of several rows?

I added a `Percentatge` column to my data.table (primitively) so my x values `Català` and `Espanyol` have the same percentatge:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYhUe.png)

but when I try to add the labels to the graph, the number appears repeated as many times as rows contributed to the bar, so nothing can be read:

```
 p + geom_text(aes(label =Percentatge), vjust = 0.5)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vp97W.png)

what can I do to avoid the repetitions and to set its position on the bar?

Comment: use `stat_bin()` argument

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using these two posts I could answer my question:

[adding overlap data label over bar chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49718365/adding-data-labels-above-geom-col-chart-with-ggplot2)

[draw the sum value above the stacked bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30656846/draw-the-sum-value-above-the-stacked-bar-in-ggplot2)

To just remove the overlaps you can use argument `check_overlaps=T` in `geom_text()` .
However to solve my problem I had to create a new dataframe:

```
m3 <- aggregate(cat$Publicacions, by=list(Llengua=cat$Llengua), FUN = sum)
m3 <- as.data.frame(m3)
```

and use it in `geom_text` like this:

```
 + geom_text(aes(x=Llengua, y=x, label=x), data=m3, vjust=-0.2)
```