# Labels geom_bar in ggplot R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this code

```
ggplot(authors_interest_sex_count, aes(Country, freq, fill=Gender)) + 
geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge") + geom_text(aes(label = freq), vjust=-1)
```

and I got this image:
[image]

as you can see, the labels for each country are completely vertical, and I think the optimal solution would having each label on top of their column. What should I change or add in my code? Thanks in advance!

Comment: This question shows how you can rotate labels https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1330989/rotating-and-spacing-axis-labels-in-ggplot2?rq=1

Comment: To put labels above the column, you could just add another `geom_text()`, with `aes(y = [the tallest bar size]`) and maybe some `vjust`. Unless you mean at the top of the whole graph.

Comment: I think OP wants this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12018499/how-to-put-labels-over-geom-bar-for-each-bar-in-r-with-ggplot2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Roman Luštrik commented, the answer I was looking for is

```
ggplot(authors_interest_sex_count, aes(Country, freq, fill=Gender)) + 
geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge") + 
geom_text(aes(label = freq), position=position_dodge(width=0.9), vjust=-1)
```

[image]
Thanks!