# How to show labels of both bars in a grouped bar chart using ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I am using the `ggplot2` package to plot a grouped bar chart. I am having a hard time  trying to show the labels above each bars. It seems that my code is simply showing the sum of each group. It is may be important to point out that my dataframe `df3` consist of only 3 categorical variables (hence why I am using count in the codes below).

```
ggplot(df3, aes(SubDept2, ..count..)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(fill = Attrition), position = "dodge")+
  geom_text(aes(label=..count..),stat='count',position=position_dodge(0.9))+
  theme_minimal()+
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Paired")+
  labs(x="Sub Dept",y="Count")
```

Here is how my plot looks (cropped image):

[image: my plot]

Here is how my sample data (df3) looks like:

```
Attrition   Dept               SubDept2
Yes         Administration     Finance
Yes         Operations         F&B
Yes         Operations         F&B
No          Operations         Rooms Division
```

Comment: Might this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12018499/how-to-put-labels-over-geom-bar-for-each-bar-in-r-with-ggplot2?rq=1 Please provide example data.

Comment: Unfortunately, no because in that example, a column of values already exist. I have updated my question with sample data of data frame df3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just include `fill=Attrition` in the original `ggplot()` call.

```
df3 <- data.frame(
  Attrition = sample(c('Yes','no'),size = 100,replace = T),
  Dept = sample(c('Administration','Operations'),size=100,replace=T),
  SubDept2 = sample(c('Finance','F&B','Rooms Division'),size=100,replace=T)
)

df3

ggplot(df3, aes(SubDept2, ..count..,,fill=Attrition)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(fill = Attrition), position = "dodge")+
  geom_text(aes(label=..count..),stat='count',position=position_dodge(0.9))+
  theme_minimal()+
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Paired")+
  labs(x="Sub Dept",y="Count")
```

[image]