# adding a simple legend that includes a chosen text using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, manual

let's say I have this simple df with its plot as follows :

```
df = data.frame(a = c('person1','person2','person3'),
                b = c(10,20,30))



ggplot(df)+aes(x=a,y=b,fill=b)+
  geom_bar(stat='identity')
```

the outcome

[image]

I wish that the legend is a box that **only** includes (for example) the following phrase :
TOTAL = 60

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to put labels over geom\_bar for each bar in R with ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12018499/how-to-put-labels-over-geom-bar-for-each-bar-in-r-with-ggplot2)

Comment: unfortunately no I have already checked it out.

Comment: `+ scale_fill_continuous(name = "TOTAL = 60")`

Comment: yeah but I want to remove the grading scale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create an `annotation` with a `label`. Make sure to create some space by changing the `plot.margin` and `clip` off the coords. You can play with the settings. Here is a reproducible example:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df)+aes(x=a,y=b,fill=b)+
  geom_bar(stat='identity') +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off") +
  annotate("label", x = Inf, y = 20, hjust = -0.1, label = "TOTAL = 60", size = 3) +
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(1,5,1,1), "lines"),
        legend.position = 'none')
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-12-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

You could use `richtext` when loading `ggtext` to rotate an annotated box like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggtext)
ggplot(df)+aes(x=a,y=b,fill=b)+
  geom_bar(stat='identity') +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off") +
  annotate("richtext", x = Inf, y = 20, vjust = 2, label = "TOTAL = 60", size = 3, angle = 90) +
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(1,5,1,1), "lines"),
        legend.position = 'none')
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-12-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Hi @Anas116 , You could add `angle = 90`.

Comment: Thank you so much. will delete the comments now so readers don't get distracted