# How to plot multi-variable data

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this dataframe called `mydf`. I have `gene` column with the unique gene names and the `searched_` (searched that genes in these many individuals) and `found_` (found in these many individuals) columns with these genes. I want to plot a graph, but not sure what would be the best way to do in R.  I would like to see `searched` bars and the `found` bars sitting on top of each other. Is that possible to get?

```
     mydf<-structure(c("FLT3-TKD", "DNMT3A", "IDH1", "190", "0", "190", 
"5.26315789473684", "NaN", "6.8421052631579", "186", "0", "188", 
"4.83870967741935", "NaN", "7.97872340425532", "123", "0", "123", 
"7.31707317073171", "NaN", "8.13008130081301"), .Dim = c(3L, 
7L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("gene", "searched_man", "found_man", 
"searched_cat", "found_cat", "searched_goat", "found_goat")))
```

Comment: In general, ggplot2 works better with [tidy data](http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.html).  Formatting your data into tidy data will also make it easier for people to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## A base R solution:

#### Read in data

Using your code, I ended up with a matrix full of characters. That's no good.

```
mydf <- as.data.frame(mydf)
mydf[, -1] <- lapply(mydf[, -1], function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))
str(mydf)
```

#### Get it into long format

```
mydf2 <- data.frame(gene = mydf$gene,
                    animal = rep(c('man', 'cat', 'goat'), each = nrow(mydf)),
                    searched = unlist(mydf[, seq(2, ncol(mydf) - 1, 2)]),
                    found = unlist(mydf[, seq(3, ncol(mydf), 2)]),
                    row.names = NULL)
```

Gives:

```
      gene animal searched    found
1 FLT3-TKD    man      190 5.263158
2   DNMT3A    man        0      NaN
3     IDH1    man      190 6.842105
4 FLT3-TKD    cat      186 4.838710
5   DNMT3A    cat        0      NaN
6     IDH1    cat      188 7.978723
7 FLT3-TKD   goat      123 7.317073
8   DNMT3A   goat        0      NaN
9     IDH1   goat      123 8.130081
```

An example of a plot would be (You gave zero information about what you wanted to see):

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mydf2, aes(x = animal, y = found / searched)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity') +
  facet_wrap(~gene)
```

[image]

Another example then:

```
mydf2$not_found <- mydf2$searched - mydf2$found
mydf3 <- tidyr::gather(mydf2, 'type', 'val', found:not_found)

ggplot(mydf3, aes(x = animal, y = val, fill = type)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity') +
  facet_wrap(~gene)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but it does not show the `found` and `searched` group of data?

Comment: I would like to see searched bars and the found stats sitting on top of each searched bar. Is that possible to get?

Comment: It shows the proportion of found. Again, I knew little about your data and only stated that you wanted 'a graph'. You want a stacked bargraph?

Comment: Category wise, your graph looks good, but I also wanted to have found and searched data to be represented.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: How do you put actual numbers in the second plot?

Comment: Maybe search first. For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6455088/how-to-put-labels-over-geom-bar-in-r-with-ggplot2