# How to use frequency in ggMarginal

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is there any way to put the count in marginal histogram in this plot?

```
ggMarginal(p1, margins = "x", size = 2, type = "histogram",
           col = "blue", fill = "orange")
```

(source: https://github.com/daattali/ggExtra)

[image]

Comment: @MarcoSandri I think they want this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6455088/how-to-put-labels-over-geom-bar-in-r-with-ggplot2

Comment: The answer seems to be in the post that you have linked to. Have you tried the examples there?

Comment: yes the link has explained well, I tried to pass the count in the y-axis of the marginal histogram but it doesn't work in the outcome figure. Here is the code I used. 


ggMarginal(p, margins = "x", size = 2, type = "histogram",xparams = list(alpha=0.6, aes(y = ..count..)), col = "blue", fill = "orange")