# ggplot plotting bars that show the sum of other columns

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, bar-chart

Hello and happy holidays
my data looks like:

```
ID <- c(1,2,3,4)
time_1 <- c(12,20,31,18)
time_2 <- c(5,8,11,7)
time_3 <- c(15,5,9,17)
total_time <- c(32,33,51,42)
data_test<- data.frame(ID,time_1,time_2,time_3,total_time)
data_test %>% glimpse()

$ ID         <dbl> 1, 2, 3, 4
$ time_1     <dbl> 12, 20, 31, 18
$ time_2     <dbl> 5, 8, 11, 7
$ time_3     <dbl> 15, 5, 9, 17
$ total_time <dbl> 32, 33, 51, 42
```

the variable `total_time` is the `sum` of the other `time` columns.
I need to plot  `total_time`  with bars for each `ID`  in a way that in each bar I can see the amount of all three `time`  columns in order to see each time column within the  `total_time`  bar linked to each `ID`.

I understand it is an easy problem for most of you folks and I apologize for taking your time. It's just bugging me now.

Thank you and look forward to hearing from you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want a stacked bar chart. In ggplot this is easily done in combination with pivot_longer()

```
data_test %>% pivot_longer(time_1:time_3)  %>%
  ggplot() + 
  geom_bar(aes(ID, value, fill=name),position = "stack",stat = "identity" )
```

[image]

Comment: Can I show the value of each Stack in the corresponding part? as well as the total value on top of each bar? Thanks

Comment: Yes, check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6455088/how-to-put-labels-over-geom-bar-in-r-with-ggplot2 for it. You can use geom_text() for it