# ggplot2: plot a bar graph by rank and label each bar with its absolute value, in a faceted plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar, facet-grid, geom-text

I need to label each bar from `d_ranked_long` (height = rank) with its rank's absolute value in `d_long$value`, so I added  `geom_text(data = d_long, aes(x=parameter, label=value))` to the `ggplot` at the end but got this error.

```
Error in `f()`:
! Aesthetics must be valid data columns. Problematic aesthetic(s): y = rank. 
Did you mistype the name of a data column or forget to add after_stat()?
Backtrace:
 1. base `<fn>`(x)
 2. ggplot2:::print.ggplot(x)
 4. ggplot2:::ggplot_build.ggplot(x)
 5. ggplot2 by_layer(function(l, d) l$compute_aesthetics(d, plot))
 6. ggplot2 f(l = layers[[i]], d = data[[i]])
 7. l$compute_aesthetics(d, plot)
 8. ggplot2 f(..., self = self)
```

[image]

With the `geom_text()` command, as solved here [How to put labels over geom_bar in R with ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6455088/how-to-put-labels-over-geom-bar-in-r-with-ggplot2), I'm telling R: with each (x,y) in `d_long_ranked`, grab the `value` in the corresponding position in `d_long` and put it on top of the bar. For example, the first bar in the first panel (vs = 0, am = 0) should have 3.44 on top of it, the second bar in the first panel should have 8.00 on top of it, and so on.

sample data

```
d_wide <- head(mtcars) %>%
  rownames_to_column(var = "make_model") %>%   select(!c(make_model,gear, carb))
```

absolute values in long format

```
d_long <-  d_wide  %>%
  pivot_longer(!c(vs, am), names_to = "parameter", values_to = "value")
```

Save the ranks in a separate dataframe

```
d_ranked <-  data.frame(d_wide [,c(8:9)],
           t(apply(d_wide[,-c( 8:9)], 1, 
                   rank, ties.method='min')))
```

the ranks in long format

```
d_ranked_long <- d_ranked  %>%
  pivot_longer(!c(vs, am), names_to = "parameter", values_to = "rank")
```

The x-axis ticks need to be in the following order:

```
d_ranked_long$parameter <- factor(d_ranked_long$parameter, levels = c("wt", "cyl", "drat", "hp",
                                                        "disp", "qsec","mpg"))

d_long$parameter <- factor(d_long$parameter, levels = c("wt", "cyl", "drat", "hp",
                                                        "disp", "qsec","mpg"))
```

put everything together

```
d_ranked_long %>%
ggplot(aes(x=parameter, y=rank)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(data = d_long, aes(x=parameter, label=value)) +
  facet_grid(am ~ vs) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))
```

Comment: The problem is that `geom_text` is inheriting aes `y = rank` but `rank` is not a `d_long` column. You need to revise your data wrangling code.

Comment: There is no reason why you have two data sets, why not `d <- cbind(d_ranked_long, value= d_long$value)` and plot `d`? I'm only seeing a problem, the lower left plot has 2 labels per bar.