# Put labels over geom_bar in R with ggplot2, dont know what my y is

Tags: r, ggplot2, label

I would like to have the individual values ​​of the species above the bars, i use data from an excel csv file, commands like  `geom_text(aes(label=y)` don't work for me, because i don't know what my y is.

My code looks like this:

```
ggplot(R_Sandbach, aes(x = fct_infreq(Species), colour = Species)) +
  geom_bar(fill = "white") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(
    axis.text.x =
      element_text(angle = 90, size = 5)
  ) +
  xlab("Fischarten") +
  ylab("Individuenanzahl")
```

[This is a small part of the date im using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TcZH1.png)

[And this is how i want the bar chart to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dmf4n.png)

Comment: Try `geom_text(aes(label=..count..), stat = "count", vjust = -.1)` which using stat ="count" will compute the counts which could be referenced via `..count..` and mapped on y.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to put labels over geom_bar in R with ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6455088/how-to-put-labels-over-geom-bar-in-r-with-ggplot2)

Comment: @stefan code works, regarding the y-problem do you know how i could use commands like `geom_bar(stat = "identity")` to change the bar colour. I get the error *geom_bar requires the following missing aesthetics: y*.

Comment: The `stat` has nothing to do with the colors. (: The bar color is set via the `fill` aes, i.e. use `fill=Species` inside `aes` (perhaps instead of color which is for the bar outline) and remove (!!) `fill = "white"`. If you want specific colors you could set them via `scale_fill_manual`.