# How to create representation for multi-level data

Tags: r

I have a dataset of 3 columns (library, its methods, the number of how many times a method is called)

[image]

I created the following bars using `ggbarplot` function, where each bar represent one method, the x-axis is the library name and the y-axis the frequency of method calls.

[image]

However, with some libraries there are so many methods making the bar chart looks unpretty, I have tried to stack the bars, but still looks confusing. is there any alternative way for e.g. grouping the data? only representing median of calls? types of representation other than bars, I am new to R and really want to know the alternative.

Comment: For starters, see these links about ggplot2 geom_bar labels: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12018499/3358272, https://stackoverflow.com/q/6455088/3358272; two-categ-vars https://stackoverflow.com/q/74636143/3358272. Also see https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_bar.html and https://r-graph-gallery.com/218-basic-barplots-with-ggplot2.html for more examples of barplots.