# How do I create this grouped barchart using R ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Environment:
R Console
RMySQL
ggplot2

I connected my mysql table and have this as an output

| Category | Dataset1 | Dataset2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 30 | 60 |
| B | 70 | 40 |

[image]

I am having difficulties trying to understand how I can get ggplot to output a grouped bar chart similar to

[image]

I tried following the instructions at https://r-graph-gallery.com/48-grouped-barplot-with-ggplot2 > Grouped barchart but I can't seem to wrap my head around how it's supposed to be configured.

Comment: ggplot2 is going to prefer the data in "long" format, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/2185252/3358272, https://stackoverflow.com/q/68058000/3358272; from there, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/12018499/3358272, https://stackoverflow.com/q/6455088/3358272; two-categ-vars https://stackoverflow.com/q/74636143/3358272 for good discussions on ggplot2 and grouped bar plots.

Comment: Thank you for the directions! Am new to ggplot and the links above helped to provide context on how to structure data : )