# Visualising barcharts as a percentage - ggplot2 on R

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

I'm quite new to R and using this community so apologies if this is a silly question. I am having some issues with visualising my data. I have detailed the code and an image of how this looks below.

```
ggplot(df1, aes(x = variable1)) +
  geom_bar() +
  labs(title = 'A', x = 'B')

ggplot(df2, aes(x = variable2)) +
  geom_bar() +
  labs(title = 'A', x = 'B')
```

this is the plot of df1. Df2 is very similar, albeit different values

[image: ggplot]

I am hoping to show the variables as a percentage of one another, to allow direct comparison between the datasets. For example, if the left hand column is 60% of the overall value for the first dataset, I want to be able to compare this to the second dataset where the lefthand column is perhaps 50% of the overall value for that dataset.

Alternatively, if there's a way to layer the two datasets on top of one another to allow comparison that would be great too! This would have to be as a percentage of each dataset though, as df1 and df2 are different sizes, therefore a comparison of the numerical values would not tell as full a picture.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Do any from https://stackoverflow.com/q/12018499/3358272, https://stackoverflow.com/q/6455088/3358272 (two-categ-vars https://stackoverflow.com/q/74636143/3358272) answer your question? There are a few examples in each.

Comment: The wording of your question is a little unclear. Are you seeking to add a percentage label over each bar? Change the y-axis from count to overall percentage? Or something else?

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on using `geom_bar`, in your geom_bar(), just include `aes(..count../sum(..count..))`, and it will be the proportions of the total.

You may also want your y-axis showing percentage by defining the scale with `+scale_y_continues(labels=percent)`.